# Предлагаю удалить метку "грамотная"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Под меткой [грамотная](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f) числится всего 6 вопросов. Все от одного участника и все достаточно свежие. Предлагаю заменить метку в этих вопросах на "грамотная речь", а саму метку [грамотная](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f) удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Метки объединены, синоним создан. Спасибо за помощь!